# Why do no Python DLLs built with MSVC load with mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, visual-c++, mod-wsgi

I recently updated from Python 2.5 to 2.7 (I tried 2.6 during my hassles) and while everything works fine from the command line or in the Django runserver, mod_wsgi cannot load any module that contains DLLs (pyd) built with MSVC.

For example, if I build my own versions of pycrypto or lxml then I will get the following error only from mod_wsgi:

```
ImportError at /
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Even the official PIL binaries will fail to import the _imaging C module in mod_wsgi but that may be another problem.

However, if I use a version of pycrypto built with MinGW from somewhere like http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto then it will import fine even in mod_wsgi. I don't find this solution satisfactory though since the whole reason I updated Python was to avoid needing to hunt for prebuilt binaries and I can't build them myself because MinGW fails >50% of the time for me.

EDIT2:
I noticed this in Python27/Lib/distutils/msvc9compiler.py on lines 680-705:

```
try:
    # Remove references to the Visual C runtime, so they will
    # fall through to the Visual C dependency of Python.exe.
    # This way, when installed for a restricted user (e.g.
    # runtimes are not in WinSxS folder, but in Python's own
    # folder), the runtimes do not need to be in every folder
    # with .pyd's.
    manifest_f = open(manifest_file)
    try:
        manifest_buf = manifest_f.read()
    finally:
        manifest_f.close()
    pattern = re.compile(
        r"""<assemblyIdentity.*?name=("|')Microsoft\."""\
        r"""VC\d{2}\.CRT("|').*?(/>|</assemblyIdentity>)""",
        re.DOTALL)
    manifest_buf = re.sub(pattern, "", manifest_buf)
    pattern = "<dependentAssembly>\s*</dependentAssembly>"
    manifest_buf = re.sub(pattern, "", manifest_buf)
    manifest_f = open(manifest_file, 'w')
    try:
        manifest_f.write(manifest_buf)
    finally:
        manifest_f.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```

This probably explains why everything works from the command line but not in mod_wsgi. Commenting all this out seems to fix the problem but doesn't feel like the proper fix. The question now is where to put msvcr90.dll so that Apache can use it? I notice that Apache's bin folder contains msvcr70.dll and msvcr80.dll but putting 90 in there doesn't work.

Comment: Skipping remove manifest worked for me under IIS too with pyodbc

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue and eventually found a solution [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.enthought.devel/29309): download/update your apache server with one from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know anything about mod_wsgi, I dare to guess that the most probable reason is missing runtime dependencies. You may want to inspect your MSVC-build with *Dependency Walker* that ships with MSVC (e.g., in MSVC 2005, it's located at \Common7\Tools\Bin\Depends.Exe). It will show you which DLLs are required by a binary.

As another workaround, it should be possible to build your modules with statically linked runtime (see Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime -- choose "Multithreaded" (not "Multithreaded DLL"); or, if building from command line, make sure `/MT` is used instead of `/MD`). However there may be problems if runtime-dependent things (e.g. FILE* objects) cross module boundary.

***UPD*** If you have correct VC redist installed, the reason may be a problem with SxS configuration (i.e. manifest of .pyd itself is wrong or missing, or conflicts with manifest of the application that loads the .pyd). You can use `sxstrace` utility to see what exactly is going on. See [Diagnosing SideBySide failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/14/576314.aspx).

Also, did you try static linking of the runtime? Or, better yet, check what are requirements of your host process.

Comment: They're missing MSVCR90.DLL (and GPSVC and IESHIMS). I put MSVCR90.DLL alongside AES.pyd and Dependency Walker passes but Apache gives a runtime error. I do have the VC redist and MSVCR90.dll is in various folders under C:\Windows\winsxs. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited the original question to show how AES.pyd is actually built. It would have gotten mangled as a comment.

Comment: @Kyle MacFarlane - I've edited my answer in response to the comments

Comment: I've edited the question again. Any ideas on how it currently stands?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with zmq. The solution was to include the python27.dll manifest in the libzmq.pyd file (and it'll most likely work for other pyd/dll's). Make sure you use all 64-bit or all 32-bit.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\mt.exe" -inputresource:C:\windows\system32\python27.dll;#2 -outputresource:libzmq.pyd;#2
```

See https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=214