# PyCrypto not loading with mod_wsgi on Windows server 2008

Tags: windows, mod-wsgi, pycrypto

I have a project set up on Windows 2008 Server 64-bit, with Apache 2.2, mod_wsgi 3.3, django 1.2, and python 2.7 (32-bit).

I have installed PyCrypto 2.3 (for 32-bit python 2.7) using the installer found on VoidSpace:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

When I attempt to import the PyCrypto module via the interpreter, it works perfectly. I then run the Django server using: manage.py runserver

This also is performing as expected, the CSS and other static images do not show properly, but the site is working properly.

When using mod_wsgi and Apache I instead get a import error, and a note that the DLL's failed to load.

The full stacktrace has been posted on pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/hav7sqB0

I used DependencyWalker to see what dependencies  that may be missing, and downloaded all of the DLL's that appeared to be missing. Those were then copied to both the System32 windows directory, and SysWOW64 directories.

The DependencyWalker app now shows only "Delayed" dependency errors, but nothing to block functionality.

I did see the related issue: 
[Why do no Python DLLs built with MSVC load with mod_wsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706293/why-do-no-python-dlls-built-with-msvc-load-with-mod-wsgi)

However, as I stated previously, installing with the VoidSpace installers did NOT resolve the issue.

I have tried compiling with MinGW32, and I am getting the error stating that it does not know how to compile on the "nt" operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method of adding a new manifest to Apache.

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/msg/afb025dc949c7051

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this so late, but this actually worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with pyodbc.

1. Grabbed Resource Hacker:
   http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/
2. Used it to find and copy the dependency on MSVCR90 in python27/python.exe (under tree 24/1):

   ```
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity> 
   </dependentAssembly>
   ```
3. Opened up pyodbc.pyd with Resource Hacker and pasted it into the tree (under tree 24/2):